# Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)

Tags: vue.js, iview

When I follow the [`iview` document](https://www.iviewui.com/docs/guide/start#%E5%BC%95%E5%85%A5_iView):

```
import 'iview/dist/styles/iview.css'
```

in my `main.js`.

There I get the bellow output error:

```
client?7705:167 ./node_modules/iview/dist/styles/fonts/ionicons.eot?v=2.0.0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/iview/dist/styles/iview.css 7:4430-4469 7:4495-4534
 @ ./node_modules/iview/dist/styles/iview.css
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:8081 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js
```

In my `webpack.config.js`:

```
  module: {
    loaders: [
          // the url-loader uses DataUrls.
          // the file-loader emits files.
          { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
          { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "file-loader" },
          { test: /\.json$/, loader: "json" },
          {test: /\.less$/, loader: "style!css!less"},
          {test: /\.(woff|woff2)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff'},
          {test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file'},
          {test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'}
        ]
      },
    ...
```

I don't know what else should be config in my loader. 
If I do not import the `iview.css`:

```
 //import 'iview/dist/styles/iview.css'
```

there do not have this issue.

Comment: I'd try removing and re-downloading iview.

Comment: @acdcjunior I have tried reinstall iview.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
test: /\.(ttf|otf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
```

Or put an absolute path to your problem modules.

Answer (score 0):

Try using url loader like this:

```
{ test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' }
```

For more general use case, by adding suffix :

```
{
  test: /\.(jpe?g|png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?[a-z0-9=.]+)?$/, 
  loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
}
```

[source](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/38)

Comment: did you stop and re-started the server? Try using `npm install` again.

Comment: There's other solution you may look in the link. Just see the last one.

Comment: I mean look in the source that I have linked.